# Ошибка при выводе из бд

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, fetch

Ошибка от браузера (или openserver): "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result".
Нужно из бд просто вывести через php поля, делаю так:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('cant connect ot db: '. 
mysql_error());
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('Blog');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'Notes'");
do{
echo "ID - ".$myrow['id']."<br>";
echo "Note: ".$myrow['note']."<br>";
echo "date: ".$myrow['date']."<br>";
}while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH));
```

Начитался php.net и гугла, перебрал разные вариации mysql_fetch и его параметры, но все тщетно, на сайте есть предупреждение что расширение устарело и с 7 версии php не поддерживается, однако у меня ошибка про параметр, мне устарение это вроде не мешает.

Comment: вы работаете с mysqli а $result у вас mysql

Comment: Перебирал варианты, вернул все на mysql, ошибка та же, ожидает что 1 параметр будет ресурсом. Ресурс должен представлять из себя по идее $result, если верить документации, но что то я делаю не так(

Comment: Ресурс это тип данных, если внимательно читать документацию.

Comment: это я понял из нее, только как это знание поможет ? типизация то динамическая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','database');
$query = 'select * from tableName';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo "ID - ".$item['id']."<br>";
    echo "Note: ".$item['note']."<br>";
    echo "date: ".$item['date']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо большое. Видимо mysql правда утратил актуальность и нужно использовать mysqli .